Unique Question Regarding Hand Poses + Outlines
I have been having a unique issue to say the least. Currently i am using this Rig made by somebody where they have the characters hand's having separate models for animations. Examples being a thumbs up to closed fist being different models and them being swapped out during animation. this is done through Matieral Nodes and Transparent BSDF's.
Now i wish for a Grease pencil Line art to be used on the Rig for stylisation but it seems due to the fact the model has these hand models there just not visible it doesn't exactly work properly
i am wondering if there is a way to use the grease pencil or another solution for line art type stuff on Blender Rigs.



I don't think this has to do with the rig - is it even a rig? Usually in Blender this term is used for an armature with bones deforming the mesh by posing them. So the hand would change poses from thumbs up to closed fist with a single hand model and the armature changing the poses... not different hand models switching visibilities. Anyway, the problem here most likely is, making an object invisible by transparency does not actually remove the mesh, so any contour based on geometry will still have geometry to build contours upon. So probably you should rather animate the render visibility.

...but how you would usually do it if you had an actual rig for the mesh would be to simply create different poses to animate them.

Then the question remains. how would i go about doing this?

I mentioned two things: animating the render visibility rather than the transparency or do it like poses are usually done: by posing them. I still do not see how it is actually realized, no settings, nothing, not even an answer from you if there is really a rig or if you just used the term for something else...

Would you like me to link you the github where i found the rig so you could see for yourself? it seems you are confused on if its a rig or not which may be due to my poor terminology. if not thank you for the advice

On this site we prefer people to put relevant information into the question and not having to look them up on external sites. You could show screenshots (so far there is no rig visible, a picture of it would help clear at least this confusion) or upload your file here: https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question. Also the comments section is not meant for chats, this is no regular forum. You could simply have posted the link without asking for it, then everyone can decide for thenselves if I they want to look at it - I'm not the only person here.
